# Replace one line of a text file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read the first line of a text file and then replacing that line with something different. The first line is an int value, so first I changed it to +1 of what is currently.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("file.txt", true)); 

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("file.txt"));

String amount;

amount = reader.readLine();

int amount1 = Integer.parseInt(amount);
amount1 = amount1 + 1;
String amount2 = String.valueOf(amount1);
amount = amount.replace(amount, amount2);

writer.write(amount);
```

Instead of replacing the original value with the new value, it just writes the new value next to the old one.

Comment: Text files offer no notion of "replacing". When replacing some content of a text file, you need to load that file entirely in memory, apply your modification to that memory, and then rewrite the file with that memory as its new content.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you told the writer to append instead of replace via the second constructor argument of the `FileWriter`:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("file.txt", true));
```

If you want to replace the file, you have to set `append` to false:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("file.txt", false));
```

However, this replaces the **entire file** not just the first line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of Java, you can do this:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("file.txt"));
        Writer writer = new FileWriter("newfile.txt")) {
    String firstLine = reader.readLine();
    firstLine = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(firstLine) + 1);
    writer.writeLine(firstLine);
    reader.transferTo(writer);
}
```

And then replace file.txt with newfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

You must replace the entire file when changing a text file.

```
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
String firstLine = lines.get(0);
...
lines.set(0, firstLines);
Files.write(path, lines, charset);
```

However if you take care that the first line never changes in length, and has enough room,
you could use a `RandomAccessFile`, and only change that piece of text.